# Magento 2 - Google analytics / Tag manager does not track afilliates and gclid details

Tags: magento2, google-analytics

I have just updated our store at https://okulos.com.br from M1.9.4.1 to M2.3.2.

First I added Google Analytics via Magento admin panel. It tracked visits fine but I could not track sources like gclid for AdWords and others form our partners.

Then I disabled GA and enabled Tag Manager. Still getting the same issue.

Anyone can help me ?

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

We're experiencing the same issue on the latest release 2.3.4

Update: I have found the fix, I've also fully tested it on Magento 2.3.4 and all is working great now.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/0693cc2a75a1646080501176e24d3fd41a72a6b5

Comment: Answer has more descriptions  which user can understand  easily